# wordpress plugin hooks method

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin for wordpress.I need database interaction.So i need to run some queries to create table.I want to run those queries in a php function.I need to run this function when this plugin will active.What hooks should i use for this purpose?? Now i am using this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'bs_check_database_creation' );
```

This is working fine so far.But i need appropriate hooks to run this function once when this plugin will activate.
Another queries : i want add a link of this plugin in header/footer/sidebar for end user to go to the plugin end user page.How should i do this?
    Currently i've manually added a link for this in wordpress template page.
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends when you want the hook to run, But I think that `init` or `admin_init` will be right for you becasue they are the earliest ones running respectively on front and back end.

**EDIT :** (After comment) The `INIT` and `admin_init` are ment to use whenever a plugin needs to RUN, and not on first activation (or install) . writing  "*I need to run this function when this plugin will active* " is a bit confusing :-) active means when it start to run , or when it is actually **ACTIVATED** ?

If you need to run a function upon ACTIVATION , then it is a bit different..

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'o99_brsa_on_activate');


function o99_brsa_on_activate() {

// do your stuff on activation

}
```

<strike>About the links, I am not sure what you mean by end user page ... Do you mean `action links` ?
And what footer do you mean ? the Admin or the Front ? ( After answering those issues I can try and reply - Even if it is a material for another question .)</strike>

As for links in the header / footer . If ou are planning to host this plugin in the wordpress repository please know that it is somewhat against the terms ( unless you request specific permission from the user )

Anyhow , this will do :

```
function o99_add_to_footer() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', ' o99_add_to_footer');
```

Comment: Thanks  Obmerk Kronen,I need to run this function for the first time when the plugin will activate.i want to give a link in the front.I want to hook a for creating this link for the front end.

Comment: If you need to run the function when the plugin is activated or installed ( ? ) , then this is another story . please try to be more clear about what you are doing ..

Comment: +1 (and deletion of my half-finished answer).  `register_activation_hook` is the way to go

Comment: first problem is solved thanks  Obmerk Kronen.for more clear regarding second issue :I have page for front user acces in my plugin. i want to add it in header or footer or sidebar of template page for end user not admin user.

Comment: @Hobo - this is due to the confusion sometimes user have with the term "activate" . The OP wrote " ..when plugin is active..." not when plugin is activated  :-)  , hence my fisrt confusion .